# Calling the correct get route in Axios/Node

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, axios

I'm learning about Axios, Mongoose and Express and have come across the following issue. I am working on one schema that needs to have 2 different get requests accessible for when i need them. problem is that when i call the route with attending it still executes the route with info. How can i target the attending route on the backend correctly?

FRONT END
//finds a users info using findOne

```
axios.get("/api/user/" + info); //info is a variable
```

//finds a users info

```
axios.get("/api/user" + attending); //attending is a variable
```

ROUTES FILE ON BACKEND

```
router
  .route("/:info")
  .get(UserController.findOne);

router
  .route("/:attending")
  .get(UserController.findOneAndUpdate);
```

I have also tried changing the routes like below but still it hits the info route and not the attending route .

FRONT END

```
 axios.get("/api/wmUser/getAttending"  + eventCode);
```

ROUTE ON BACKEND

```
  router
      .route("/:info")
      .get(UserController.findOne);

    router
      .route("/getAttending/:attending")
      .get(UserController.findOneAndUpdate);
```

Comment: Your both the routes are same... Only your parameter is being changed that's why it is calling the only `info` route... Actually it will call the route which is written first in the code if you put `attending` route first it will it first... You need do change the route in order to make them different.

Comment: so i tried adding .route("/getAttending/:attending") on backend and axios.get("/api/wmUser/getAttending"  + eventCode); moved this infront of the other one and still no go

Comment: You forgot to use `/` in between getAttending and eventCode.... Try this `axios.get("/api/wmUser/getAttending/" + eventCode)`

Comment: that is the answer!! thank you its working.. super exciting :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an axios GET request which will target

```
router
  .route("/:info")
  .get(UserController.findOne);
```

If you want to hit the PUT route on the backend, you need to do a axios.put request on the frontend.

Both your axios get requests from the frontend will hit the get on the backend with different params (namely info and attending).

Comment: sorry i corrected the question there should not be any put calls only gets